# Printing RDLC on client-side

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I tried to print an RDLC upon a button click. I followed this walkthrough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140). It worked well in localhost but when I uploaded it on the server, it is not printing. I read many articles about this and I tried most of it but I can't get a work-around. This is my first time and I really need help on this matter. If possible, I really need the actual codes to print the RDLC on the client-side. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. The question is really vague. Please take a moment and read [ask] and edit your question with [mcve] and explain in detail what is the problem you are facing. Does the program crash, is there an error? Be specific.

Comment: What kind of server?